# Use of Option inside play template

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a route defined this way :

```
GET     /path/search                controllers.MyController.search(search1: Option[String], search2: Option[String])
```

I would like to be able to use it inside a template for example :

```
<table data-myurl="@routes.MyController.search("", "")">
</table>
```

I will then parametrized the search function in a Javascritp script.
But for now this doesn not compile.  What is the format to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters have the type `Option[String]`, and the empty strings `""` you have there are not `Option[String]`. If you want them to be empty by default (not present), you can use `None`:

```
@routes.MyController.search(None, None)
```

If you want them to be there, but empty strings by default, wrap the empty strings in `Some`:

```
@routes.MyController.search(Some(""), Some(""))
```